# How can I reduce the delay for dragging a file into another window or application?

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, compiz

I'm sure the delay has its reason. But it is possible to reduce the delay, which is needed to drag files from one window into another or into an application ?

Example:
If you open two nautilus windows and want to drag some files from one to the other, you (at least I) have to wait like a second to really move the file. If I'm not waiting nothing will happen. Another example would be dragging files to VLC.

Some specs:
Using a HP Pavillion dv7 1170eg. You can find detailed specs [here](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/hp-pavilion-dv7-1170eg/4507-3121_7-35271885.html).
And i'm using nvidia driver.

Comment: Could you add your specs to your question? Hardware, CPU, GPU, RAM?

Comment: Specs added (see the link)